# Could not see graphics on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows

I installed Windows Server 2003 on one of my machines. It was a long back machine and the OS was also installed long back. Its RAM is 4GB.

Until 4 days back the machine was fine and providing services. But recently its graphics got problem. Only command prompt is working. If I open Windows Explorer through "explorer.exe" through command prompt, the window gets opened but no graphics would be displayed. It is showing black desktop.

The machine is currently running as a development server. Could anyone please suggest and help me in making the machine run perfectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I found the answer. I killed the process explorer.exe with the help of below commands

```
    > tasklist
    > TaskKill /F /IM explorer.exe
```

and started the process with the below command

```
    > explorer.exe
```

It should resolve the issue at this point. If not, logoff the machine and login back. It should definitely show the result.